# Run Time error 6 Overrun in vba for excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running the following program, and get an overflow error at the first iteration once the program gets to `a`. From my understanding this shouldn't happen because I'm using Doubles which have a ridiculous amount of capacity, and a Long, but because it's only going up to 100 currently it shouldn't matter, and the code fails long before then. Here is my original inputs:

```
h0 = 1000, v0 = 0, a0 = g = -9.80665, dt = .01, m = 752.2528, b = .287875
```

and here's the code:

```
Sub drag()
    Dim h0 As Double
    Dim v0 As Double
    Dim a0 As Double
    Dim dt As Double
    Dim m As Double
    Dim b As Double
    Dim g As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim h As Double
    Dim v As Double
    Dim a As Double

    h0 = Worksheets("Drag").Cells(2, 8).Value
    v0 = Worksheets("Drag").Cells(2, 9).Value
    a0 = Worksheets("Drag").Cells(2, 10).Value
    g = Worksheets("Drag").Cells(2, 10).Value
    dt = Worksheets("Drag").Cells(2, 7).Value
    m = Worksheets("Drag").Cells(2, 4).Value
    b = Worksheets("Drag").Cells(2, 5).Value
    Debug.Print h0 & v0 & a0 & dt & m & b

    For i = 1 To 100
        v = v0 + a0 * dt
        h = 0.5 * a0 * (dt ^ 2) + v0 * dt + h0
        a = m * g - b * (v ^ 2)   'Line where overflow occurs
        v0 = v
        h0 = h
        a0 = a
        Cells(i + 2, 8) = h0
        Cells(i + 2, 9) = v0
        Cells(i + 2, 10) = a0
        Next i
    Debug.Print h0 & v0 & a0 & dt & m & b
End Sub
```

Hope this is an easy fix.

Comment: Your overflow happens when `i=14` (14th pass through the loop) and when `v = -1.689 x 10^209`. I don't know what you are trying to do, but `v` is blowing up. It would help if you describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: @John Coleman I see the problem now, I'm doing the drag equation and I forgot to divide the a term by m, thanks.

Comment: FWIW that code is **begging** for a comment explaining the computation terms and formula. Or meaningful identifiers. Or both.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: LOL, I was typing an answer when you typed that comment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Your overflow happens when i=14 (14th pass through the loop) and when v = -1.689 x 10^209. I don't know what you are trying to do, but v is blowing up. It would help if you describe what you are trying to do. – John Coleman 17 mins ago
>
> @John Coleman I see the problem now, I'm doing the drag equation and I forgot to divide the a term by m, thanks. – Anthrochange 9 mins ago

You have already identified what needs to be done.

Now for the explanation on why the overflow on `m * g - b * (v ^ 2)`. I added a watch as shown below

Consider the before and after screenshot

**Before `v = v0 + a0 * dt` is calculated**

[image]

**After `v = v0 + a0 * dt` is calculated**

[image]

What you see here is a very peculiar behaviour. A Type `Double` changing to an `Integer`

This is not normal and has been experienced before. Unfortunately this problem exists in Excel for a long time and unfortunately is also present in Excel 2016. It occurs only when you are using very large numbers. These kind of bugs are very rare, but yes, they do exist.

One can have a similar kind of experience when using `MOD` as mentioned in the below link

[The MOD Function](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ModFunction.aspx)

Comment: Aiie, is there a chance for such "metamorphosis" to occur before the overflow? Or to persist if we skipped the error through `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: Yes you can ignore the error using OERN but I have not tested the accuracy of the results. I also doubt the datatype will change back to Double :)

Answer (score 1):

The variable in question that is getting an overflow is v.  You defined it as a double, which means you can only put numbers in the range of 1.79769313486232 * 10^308 to 4.94065645841247 * 10^–324. VBA uses 8 bytes to hold the double data.  Any number outside of this huge range causes an overflow. (see [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=339929&seqNum=2) for more information about DBA data types)

How big of a number are you expecting?  A [rough estimate fo the number of atoms in the universe](https://www.universetoday.com/36302/atoms-in-the-universe/) is 1 * 10^82, and the double value range goes to almost 2 *10^308.  If you need to work with numbers that large, you're going to have to use a [different](http://web.mnstate.edu/peil/MDEV102/U3/S29/S2910.html) [method](http://www.sparknotes.com/math/algebra1/scientificnotation/section2.rhtml) because it simply won't fit in the standard VBA data types.